# Home-made "look for files in directory" function runs, but not properly

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a function that is supposed to look for all the file with the extension chosen, in the selected directory. Actually, it runs but it doesn't return anything.

I am trying to keep things simple/stupid, since I am just at the beginning of my journey in Python
Below, I reported the code.

Thanks for your help!

## THIS ONE RUNS, BUT RETURNS AN EMPTY LIST

```
import fnmatch
import glob

def lookfor(dir, ext):
    direct = glob.glob(dir)

    files = []
    for file in direct:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, ext):
            files.append(file)

    return files

print(lookfor('C:/Users/nameuser/where/folder/', '*.docx'))
```

## THIS ONE WORKS PROPERLY, BUT ONLY FOR .docx FILE, AS WRITTEN INSIDE THE FUNCT

```
import fnmatch
import glob

def lookfor(dir):
    direct = glob.glob(dir)

    files = []
    for file in direct:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.docx'):
            files.append(file)

    return files

print(lookfor('C:/Users/nameuser/where/folder/*.docx'))
```

Comment: `glob.glob(dir)` wont be useful because you are passing a directory name but not for the kind of files you are looking for. I am suspecting that `for` loop may not run because of that and hence empty list.

Comment: So, how to avoid this problem?

Comment: Take a look at code example on [this page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html)

Comment: It was so simple. Ahah thanks a lot!